# C++ Generic Swap Function

Tags: c++, templates, strtok

In my class.h i got:

```
template<class T> void Swap(T, T);
```

And in class.cpp:

```
template<class T>
void class::Swap(T& p1, T& p2)
    {
        T aux = p1;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = aux;
    }
```

When I try :

```
this->Swap<char*>(&lit[i][k], &lit[i][l]);
```

And another question:
What am i doing wrong here: i want to split my string after some delimitators ("+-") and strtok isn't working as I expected.

```
int counter = 0;
    char* s = strtok(eq_clone ," ");
    while(s != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        if(s == "")
            counter--;
        s = strtok(eq_clone ,"+-");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::swap` instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: don't use `strtok` in C++, use istream instead.

Comment: Is your definition in class.cpp meant to be of `Swap` rather than `Sort`?

Comment: "And another question" <- what was the *first* question?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Swap()` and declaration of `lit`?

Comment: @hmjd string* lit; 

template<class T> void Swap(T, T);

Comment: How is `lit` initialized? Looks like `lit = new std::string[N]` ?

Comment: BTW, the signature of declaration and definition of `Swap()` are different.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a mistake as it will never be true:

```
if(s == "")
```

this is comparing the address of `s` to the address of the string literal `""`: it is not checking if `s` is an empty string. An alternative to using `strtok()` would be [`boost::algorithm::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s("a,string+with-multiple delimiters");
    std::vector<std::string> s_tokens;

    boost::algorithm::split(s_tokens, s, boost::is_any_of(",+- "));

    std::for_each(s_tokens.begin(),
                  s_tokens.end(),
                  [] (const std::string& s)
                  {
                      std::cout << s << "\n";
                  });
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
string
with
multiple
delimiters
```

Regarding swap, as has already been stated in comments and other answer(s) just use `std::swap()`. I am guessing that `lit` is a `char[][]` so `std::swap(lit[i][k], lit[i][l]);` will do exactly what you require.

EDIT:

After comment giving declaration `string* lit` and that `lit` appears to be an array (from example usage) then use `std::swap()` in this manner:

```
std::string* lit = new std::string[4];

lit[0] = "zero";

std::swap(lit[0][1], lit[0][2]); // The characters will be passed by reference,
                                 // don't take address.

std::cout << lit[0] << "\n"; // Prints "zreo"
```

Note, that the declaration of your `Swap()` passes arguments by value (incorrect), but the definition of `Swap()` passes arguments by reference (correct). If you change the declaration of your `Swap()` and invoke it as follows it will work (if you really don't want to use `std::swap()`:

```
template<class T> void Swap(T&, T&);
                           //^ //^

Swap(lit[i][k], lit[i][l]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Why is `Swap()` a class member? Class members should somehow be tightly coupled to your classes. In most cases it is is sign of bad design if something, which does not use private members or is very similar to a method that does (i.e. a convinience method), becomes a class member. C++ is not java where everything has to belong to a class. Make your `swap()` method a free standing template method.

2) Better yet, do not reinvent the wheel. `std::swap()` is there and it works mightily well. In many cases you can expect the methods and classes provided by the standard library to work better than something you could write up.

3) In your class you called the method `Sort()`, but the question is about `Swap()`. Since you did not write what you expected to happen and what actually happens, this is the only thing I can find which might be wrong.

4) Do not use `strtok()` in C++ unless you have to. `char*` are C-Style strings and should not be used in C++. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: ok but for 4) is there a method to split the string after a delimitator in std::string? Something like string myString = "some thing", delim = ' '; string a[10] = myString.Split(delim); ?

Comment: @Dementor: see [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/53849/113124) and [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/113124).